# Eevee grease pencil glitching

Tags: grease-pencil

**Grease pencil glitching**

[image: As you can see outline grease pencil is glitching]

eevee and cycles is the same tryed restarting and tried changin texture and layer tryed enable z layer and yet it still remains

whats cousing the isue and how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you checked that your graphics drivers are up to date?

Comment: @JohnEason yup i just updated geforce and also restarted computer checked for computer updates and all

Comment: the few fixes i found 1 st just add anothere identical gresepencil 2 st tone down light behind grese pencil

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. I've never used grease pencil. Try adding more details of the problem into your question and add an image of your full Blender screen via Blender's Window Save Screenshot menu and your question will be resubmitted. Maybe someone will have an answer.